# Using CASE statement with COUNT DISTINCT on IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get a sum of all my count distinct on unique IDs.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT [business_unit])AS 'COUNT',
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '11%') THEN [business_unit] END) AS '11%',
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '49%') THEN [business_unit] END) AS '49%',
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '41%') THEN [business_unit] END) AS '41%',
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '40%') THEN [business_unit] END) AS '40%',
    [business_unit]
FROM 
    [Table]
GROUP BY 
    [business_unit]
```

ANSWER should be IN TOTALS

```
Count 3,071 | 11 = 737| 40 = 2186| 41 = 122| 49 = 25
```

[image]

Comment: You can use SUM(COUNT(....

Comment: i tried this but error MSG.
Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

,SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '11%') THEN [business_unit] END )) AS '11%'

Comment: If you group by business unit then `count(distinct business_unit)` will always be 1.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a subquery or CTE and then add them up.  Alternatively, you could phrase the logic as:

SELECT

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LEFT(business_unit, 2) IN ('11', '49', '41', '40')
                    THEN business_unit
      END) AS Total
```

Comment: I'm getting zero for this SQL

SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LEFT(business_unit, 2) IN ('11%', '49%', '41%', '40%') THEN business_unit
END) AS Total
FROM [TABLE]
GROUP BY [business_unit]

Comment: @QuicKick `in` doesn't work with `like` wildcards. It's the percent characters that aren't matching up.

Comment: @QuicKick . . . That code is not in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT` returns an `INTEGER` and the `CONCAT` function implicitly converts `INT` to `(N)(VAR)CHAR` (as appropriate).  You could try something like this

```
SELECT concat('COUNT ', COUNT(DISTINCT [business_unit])) as [COUNT],
       concat('11 = ', COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '11%') THEN [business_unit] END)) as [11%],
       concat('40 = ', COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '40%') THEN [business_unit] END)) as [40%],
       concat('41 = ', COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '41%') THEN [business_unit] END)) as [41%],
       concat('49 = ', COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '49%') THEN [business_unit] END)) as [49%],
       [business_unit]
FROM 
    [Table]
GROUP BY 
    [business_unit];
```

[EDIT] Without the string `CONCAT` the query is very similar to the code in the question.  Instead of single quotes around column labels the appropriate delimiter is/are brackets.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [business_unit]) as [COUNT],
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '11%') THEN [business_unit] END) as [11%],
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '40%') THEN [business_unit] END) as [40%],
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '41%') THEN [business_unit] END) as [41%],
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '49%') THEN [business_unit] END) as [49%],
       [business_unit]
FROM 
    [Table]
GROUP BY 
    [business_unit];
```

Comment: Would it be possible to just the totals of distinct counts for each case statement.

Comment: SELECT 
--DISTINCT

COUNT(DISTINCT [business_unit]) AS 'COUNTID'
,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '11%') THEN [business_unit] END ) AS '11%'
,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '49%') THEN [business_unit] END ) AS '49%'
,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '41%') THEN [business_unit] END ) AS '41%'
,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '40%') THEN [business_unit] END ) AS '40%'

FROM [TABLE]

--Some how this worked. I took OUT the GROUP BY--

Answer (score 0):

So I just removed GROUP BY and it was able to provide me the totals

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT [business_unit]) AS 'COUNTID'
,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '11%') THEN [business_unit] END ) AS '11%'
,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '49%') THEN [business_unit] END ) AS '49%'
,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '41%') THEN [business_unit] END ) AS '41%'
,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ([business_unit] LIKE '40%') THEN [business_unit] END ) AS '40%'
FROM [TABLE]
```

[image]